# byte [] and file - fastest way, when we have too big file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nio

I want to write byte[] to file.  byte [] is too big. For about 1-1.5 GB file.

I know , there are many ways to do that. but what is the fastest way?

Apache commons FileOutputStream or OutputStream? Or might be the fastest is nio.ByteBuffer ? 
if nio is fastest, could you give me an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "byte [] is too big"? Is it bigger than 2GB or too big to fit on heap? Can you split it into smaller arrays and process it one chunk at a time?

Comment: From 1-1.5 GB, I will update this.

Comment: I have enough heap space. Bit FileOutputStream  takes too many time for 1 GB file.

Comment: How about showing us your code? My bet is that, as in 99.999% of the cases, the problem is in your code, and not in the standard library that millions of people use every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `java.nio.Files.write(Path path, byte[] bytes, OpenOption... options)`

Comment: Why nio? is it fastest?

Comment: Javadocs doesnt say it is the fastest, however it says that Files uses file system provider to perform the file operations, so we can expect it should be efficient